# How the exact type of object is being returned even though Type Erasure has reduced T to Object

Tags: java

Here how the method "returnObj" is able to return object of type "TestGen" type even though "Type Erasure" has reduced T to Object.

```
class TestGen
{

}

class MyGeneric<T>
{
    T obj;
    MyGeneric(T giveObj)
    {
        obj = giveObj;
    }

    T returnObj()
    {
        return obj;
    }

}
public class TestGeneric {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGeneric<TestGen> mg = new MyGeneric<TestGen>(new TestGen());
        TestGen tg = mg.returnObj();

    }

}
```

Comment: Because `TestGen` inherits `Object`?

Comment: Objects don't change from one type to another.  Once a TestGen object, always a TestGen object.

Answer (score 2):

It is all compiler's trickery: since the complier knows that `MyGeneric`'s type parameter is `TestGen`, it quietly inserts a type cast behind the scene. If you decompile the call back from bytecode, it would look something like this:

```
TestGen tg = (TestGen)mg.returnObj();
```

The compiler has verified that the call is going to succeed at runtime.

Comment: Yes!  Using generics causes the compiler to insert cast operations for you, rather than you having to explicitly insert them.  You get essentially the same code either way.